# ¿Cómo hago que me salga el rectángulo de las placas?

Tags: python, opencv, pytesseract

Estaba intentando realizar algunos ajustes para este codigo de python que encontré del canal de "Aprende e ingenia", pero pese a que le di mil vueltas a ver por qué el rectangulo que se supone debe estar coloreado de negro y me debe mostrar la placa del vehiculo no aparece. Soy un novato en este tema de la programación, pero tengo mucho entusiasmo de aprender sobre todo esto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image

# -------REALIZAR VIDEOCAPTURAS--------------
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("prueba.mp4")

# Se inicializa una variable con el texto del cuadro que tendrá la placa
Ctexto = ''

# Creación del bucle while
while True:
    # Realizar la lectura de la videocaptura
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    if ret == False:
        break

    # Dibujamos un rectángulo (ACÁ ESTÁ EL PROBLEMA)
    cv2.rectangle(frame, (870, 750), (1070, 850), (0, 0, 0), cv2.FILLED)
    cv2.putText(frame, Ctexto[0:7], (900, 810), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (0, 255, 0), 2)

    # Extraer el ancho y el alto de los fotogramas
    al, an, c = frame.shape

    # Tomar el centro de la imagen
    # En x:
    x1 = int(an / 3)  # Tomamos 1/3 de la imagen
    x2 = int(x1 * 2)   # Hasta el inicio del 3/3 de la imagen

    # En y:
    y1 = int(al / 3)
    y2 = int(y1 * 2)

    # Texto
    cv2.rectangle(frame, (x1 + 160, y1 + 500), (1120, 940), (0, 0, 0), cv2.FILLED)
    cv2.putText(frame, 'Procesando Placa', (x1 + 180, y1 + 550), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (0, 255, 0), 2)

    # Ubicar el rectángulo en las zonas extraídas
    cv2.rectangle(frame, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 255, 0), 2)

    # Realizar un recorte a nuestra zona de interés
    recorte = frame[y1:y2, x1:x2]

    # Preprocesamiento de la zona de interés
    mB = np.matrix(recorte[:, :, 0])
    mG = np.matrix(recorte[:, :, 1])
    mR = np.matrix(recorte[:, :, 2])

    # Color
    Color = cv2.absdiff(mG, mB)

    # Binarizar la imagen
    _, umbral = cv2.threshold(Color, 40, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

    # Extraer los contornos de la zona seleccionada
    contornos, _ = cv2.findContours(umbral, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    # Ordenar del más grande al más pequeño
    contornos = sorted(contornos, key=lambda x: cv2.contourArea(x), reverse=True)

    # Dibujar los contornos extraídos
    for contorno in contornos:
        area = cv2.contourArea(contorno)
        if 500 < area < 5000:  # Detectar la placa
            x, y, ancho, alto = cv2.boundingRect(contorno)

            # Extraer las coordenadas
            xpi = x + x1  # Coordenada de la placa en X inicial
            ypi = y + y1  # Coordenada de la placa en Y inicial

            xpf = x + ancho + x1  # Coordenada de la placa en X final
            ypf = y + ancho + y1  # Coordenada de la placa en Y final

            # Dibujar el rectángulo
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (xpi, ypi), (xpf, ypf), (255, 255, 0), 2)

            # Extraer los pixeles
            placa = frame[ypi:ypf, xpi:xpf]

            # Extraer el ancho y el alto de los fotogramas
            alp, anp, cp = placa.shape

            # Procesar los pixeles para extraer los valores de las placas
            Mva = np.zeros((alp, anp))

            # Normalizar las matrices
            mBp = np.matrix(placa[:, :, 0])
            mGp = np.matrix(placa[:, :, 1])
            mRp = np.matrix(placa[:, :, 2])

            # Crear una máscara
            for col in range(0, alp):
                for fil in range(0, anp):
                    Max = max(mRp[col, fil], mGp[col, fil], mBp[col, fil])
                    Mva[col, fil] = 255 - Max

            # Binarizar la imagen
            _, bin = cv2.threshold(Mva, 150, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

            # Convertir la matriz en imagen
            bin = bin.reshape(alp, anp)
            bin = Image.fromarray(bin)
            bin = bin.convert("L")

            # Asegurarse de tener un buen tamaño de placa
            if alp >= 36 and anp >= 82:
                # Declarar la dirección de Pytesseract
                pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'

                # Extraemos el texto
                config = "--psm 1"
                texto = pytesseract.image_to_string(bin, config=config)

                # If para no mostrar basura xd
                if len(texto) >= 7:
                    #print(texto[0:7])
                    Ctexto = texto
                    # Mostrar los valores que nos interesan
                    # cv2.putText(frame, Ctexto[0:7], (910, 810), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
                    break

                    # Mostrar el recorte
                    # cv2.imshow("Recorte", bin)


    #Mostramos el recorte en gris
    cv2.imshow("Vehiculos", frame)

    #Leemos una tecla
    t = cv2.waitKey(1)

    if t == 27:
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Intenté ejecutar este bloque de código antes, y realmente si lo borro no pasa nada:

```
# Dibujamos un rectángulo
cv2.rectangle(frame, (870, 750), (1070, 850), (0, 0, 0), cv2.FILLED)
cv2.putText(frame, Ctexto[0:7], (900, 810), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
```

``
También intente abrir una ventana vacía para verificar que el OpenCV funcionara correctamente y pues parece que si

Comment: Dos cosas: tal vez sea tonto de preguntar, pero es posible... no será el rectangulo del mismo color del fondo (o muy similar)? Además, aunque para vos sea obvio que ahí hay una patente, eso no es tan facil de detectar para la computadora por ahora. Estarán las imagenes que usas borrosas? Alguna diferencia significativa entre la imagen de referencia y la de la patente, color, forma? Probaste tu programa usando las imagenes originales que usa el canal "Aprende e Ingenia"?

Comment: Pues yo diría que el fondo no es para nada parecido, acabé de editar la pregunta con capturas del video y de lo que se me ejecuta en mi caso. Y pues de imagenes borrosas, realmente no creo, fue un video grabado en esa parte en específico de manera en la cual la placa fuera reconocible, por cierto, gracias por responder al menos, estoy desde hace horas como desquiciado buscando la solución

Comment: De nada :D por cierto, mirando detenidamente tu código, noté que los rectangulos se crean en el bucle for contour in contours. Si lo que está allí dentro no se ejecuta, puede ser o que contours está vacío o que alguno de tus condicionales está dando False en todas las iteraciones. Para comprobar esto, poné un print en la parte donde debería crear el rectangulo. Si muestra en consola lo que indicas, es que se ejecuta esa parte del for.